# Passing variable to PHP using Ajax/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is probably very simply but I cannot figure it out. I am using a jquery script I found to display a timer. I then want to send the number of seconds to a PHP file. Below is the script, if I just alert the value variable, it contains the correct data, so I am accessing it correctly but its empty on the PHP side when it arrives.

```
$('.get-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
  var value = $('.timer').data('seconds');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: { value : value },
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
      alert(result);
    }
  });
});
```

The result alert displays empty based on this test php file

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    echo $value;
  } else {
    $value = "Empty!";
    echo $value;
  }
?>
```

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: The code you have should work fine - assuming it's in a document.ready event handler and the `value` is filled correctly. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: try to log your value to the console, or otherwite try to set the value manually, like: value = 10; then see how it goes

Comment: where are you seeing the result in php?

Comment: Took a network trace on my load balancer and can see the value being sent, turns out my apache box is responding with a 302

Answer (score 0):

I thought you must add a header to Ajax object.
**edits** :

1. change var name
2. check URL address
3. add header

```js
$('.get-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
  //change this name !
  var value_data = $('.timer').data('seconds');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',  //make sure correct address
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},   //add header is so important
    data: { value : value_data },
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
      alert(result);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: The var value is correct if I just alert the var.
The URL is correct, I get the "Empty" echoed back from the php file
Added header ... no change

Comment: add the headers part this is important,  'headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},'

Answer (score 0):

You must end php hier is a worked example:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['value'])){
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    echo ($value)?$value:'Empty';
  die;}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="timer" data-seconds="2"></p>
<button class="get-timer-btn">BTN</button>
<script>
$('.get-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
  var value = $('.timer').data('seconds');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: { value : value },
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
      alert(result);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```